# Create is converting properties to nil and update doesn't generate a sql update statement

Tags: activerecord, model, ruby-on-rails-3.1, controller

Rails 3.1 
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]
sqlite3

I have a model called usecase that is not creating or updating properly. When I create a new record the text columns are set to nil and the integer values based on select values are captured. There is also an integer value in an input field that is user supplied and it is set to nil.

When I attempt an update the log shows that no sql input statement is created or executed. I am able to create new records and update them properly from the console.

Here is the model code (note all validations have been removed):

```
class Usecase < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :due_at, :failure_end_condition, :frequency, :level_id, :number, :performance_target,
              :primary_actor_id, :priority_id, :profile_id, :project_id, :purpose, :success_end_condition,
              :title, :trigger, :usecase_status_id
has_many :actor_assignments
has_many :actors, :through => :actor_assignments
has_many :pre_conditions
has_many :post_conditions
has_many :usecase_as_conditions
has_many :scenarios
has_many :variations
belongs_to :profile
belongs_to :project
belongs_to :usecase_status
```

Here is the controller code for: class UsecasesController < ApplicationController

```
def new
  @usecase = Usecase.new
  @usecase.profile_id = current_user.profile.id
  @usecase.set_defaults(current_user.profile.default_project_id)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @usecase }
  end
end

def edit
  @usecase = Usecase.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {render "edit"}
    format.json { render json: @usecase }
  end
end

def create
  @usecase = Usecase.new(params[:usecases])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @usecase.save
      format.html { redirect_to [:edit, @usecase], notice: 'Usecase was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @usecase, status: :created, location: @usecase }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @usecase.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def update
  @usecase = Usecase.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @usecase.update_attributes(params[:usecases])
      format.html { redirect_to @usecase, notice: 'Usecase was successfully updated.' }
      format.json {  head :ok}
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
      format.json { render json: @usecase.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Log For New Record Insert (note that the received parameter for :title has a value, but in the insert statement it is nil.

```
    Started POST "/usecases" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-24 14:50:40 -0800
  Processing by UsecasesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Uscho1j5FCsbdRUhTyg/Ji79yyPwyMRZUcyiWYtSw54=", 
    "usecase"=>{"number"=>"1", "title"=>"Create New Record", "due_at"=>"2012-02-07"}, "usecases"=>{"project_id"=>"2", 
                "usecase_status_id"=>"1", "profile_id"=>"3"}, "commit"=>"Create Usecase"}
  [1m[36mSQL (3.0ms)[0m  [1m
 INSERT INTO "usecases" ("created_at", "due_at", "failure_end_condition", "frequency", "level_id", "lock_version", 
                         "number", "performance_target", "primary_actor_id", "priority_id", "profile_id", "project_id", 
                         "purpose", "success_end_condition", "title", "trigger", "updated_at", "usecase_status_id") 
  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)[0m  
 [["created_at", Tue, 24 Jan 2012 22:50:40 UTC +00:00], ["due_at", nil], ["failure_end_condition", nil], ["frequency", nil], ["level_id", nil], 
  ["lock_version", 0], ["number", nil], ["performance_target", nil], ["primary_actor_id", nil], ["priority_id", nil], ["profile_id", 3], 
  ["project_id", 2], ["purpose", nil], ["success_end_condition", nil], ["title", nil], ["trigger", nil], 
  ["updated_at", Tue, 24 Jan 2012 22:50:40 UTC +00:00], ["usecase_status_id", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/usecases/2/edit
Completed 302 Found in 71ms
```

Log for an update (note no UPDATE sql statement is created)

```
    Started PUT "/usecases/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-24 14:57:04 -0800
  Processing by UsecasesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Uscho1j5FCsbdRUhTyg/Ji79yyPwyMRZUcyiWYtSw54=", "usecase"=>{"number"=>"1", "project_id"=>"2", 
               "title"=>"Update Row With New Title", "usecase_status_id"=>"1", "due_at"=>"2012-01-28", "profile_id"=>"3"}, "commit"=>"Update Usecase", "id"=>"2"}
  [1m[36mUsecase Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "usecases".* FROM "usecases" WHERE "usecases"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", "2"]]
  [1m[35mProject Load (1.0ms)[0m  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" ORDER BY title ASC
  [1m[36mUsecaseStatus Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "usecase_statuses".* FROM "usecase_statuses" ORDER BY rank ASC[0m
  [1m[35mProfile Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" ORDER BY last_name ASC, first_name ASC
Rendered usecases/test.html.erb within layouts/application (147.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb (2.0ms)
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 3 LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mProfile Load (1.0ms)[0m  SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."user_id" = 3 LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mAccount Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."id" = 3 LIMIT 1[0m
Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (330.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 674ms (Views: 614.0ms | ActiveRecord: 7.0ms)
```

Thanks for looking at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't that be 
`@usecase = Usecase.new(params[:usecase])`
 and 
`if @usecase.update_attributes(params[:usecase])` 
respectively?

Hope that fixes it.